# JavaScript click handler not working as expected inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent, jquery-events

I'm trying to learn JS and got an issue.

I tried many things and googled but all in vain. Following piece of code doesn't work as expected. I should get value of `i` on click but it always returns 6. I'm pulling my hair out; please help.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

    console.log(i);

    $("#div" + i).click(
        function() {
            alert(i);
        }
    );
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmXcF/)

Comment: You're dealing with a closure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 164, accepted):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmXcF/1/)

This is a classic JavaScript closure problem. Reference to the `i` object is being stored in the click handler closure, rather than the actual value of `i`.

Every single click handler will refer to the same object because there’s only one counter object which holds 6 so you get six on each click.

The workaround is to wrap this in an anonymous function and pass i as argument. Primitives are copied by value in function calls.

```
for(var i=1; i<6; i++) {
     (function (i) {
        $("#div" + i).click(
            function () { alert(i); }
        );
     })(i);
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmXcF/4/)

Or you can use ['let'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead `var` to declare `i`. `let` gives you fresh binding each time. It can only be used in ECMAScript 6 `strict mode`.

```
'use strict';

for(let i=1; i<6; i++) {

        $("#div" + i).click(
            function () { alert(i); }
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 41):

The problem is that as you iterate through the loop, `i` is incremented.  It ends up with a value of 6.  When you say `alert(i)` you are asking javascript to tell you what the value of `i` is **at the time the link is clicked**, which by that point is 6.

If you want to get the contents of the box instead you could do something like this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  $("#div" + i).click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div5">5</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$("#div" + i).click(
    function() {
        alert(i);
    }
);
```

It's because it's using the value of `i` as a closure. `i` is remembered through a closure which increases at every stage of the foor loop.

```
$("#div" + i).click(function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).attr("id").replace(/div/g, ""));
});
```